# LabVIEW print front panel PDF with specific filename

Tags: pdf-generation, labview

I'm using the Easy Print VI to print my application front panel. But I'm unable to predefine the filename and auto save it.

Answer (score 0):

The "Save report to File.vi" let's you specify the name of the VI. Note that this VI does NOT work with a standard report, but with HTML. I do not have the report generation toolbox so cannot test for the rest.

Another way is to print the report with a PDF printer. I get a pop-up dialog with the standard Microsoft PDF printer but that is probably avoidable with better PDF printers.

[image: VI snippet with report and print methods]